# String index out of range (Python3)

Tags: python

I keep getting string index out of range on line 4 (if s[i] != s[end-i]:) but I can't figure out why. I ran my code on visualizer but that didn't help me.
The code is supposed to give me the longest palindromic substring after I input a string s

here is my code:

```
def isSubPalindrome (s,start,end):
    isPal = True
    for i in range (start,end):
        if s[i] != s[end-i]:
            isPal = False
    return isPal

def longestPalSubsB (s):

    MaxLen = 0
    for i in range (len(s)-1):
        for j in range (i,len(s)-1):
            st = ""
            for k in range (i,j):
                st = st + s[k]
                if isSubPalindrome (st,i,j) == True and len(st)>MaxLen:
                    MaxLen = len (st)
                    start = i
                    end = j

    return s[start,end]

s = input("Enter a string: ")

print (longestPalSubsB(s))
```

```
Enter a string: aceexcivicgrfdds
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-64661b5bf324>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Rayan/Desktop/AUB Spring 2019/EECE 230 /HW/Homework 4/Problem2b.py', wdir='/Users/Rayan/Desktop/AUB Spring 2019/EECE 230 /HW/Homework 4')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Rayan/Desktop/AUB Spring 2019/EECE 230 /HW/Homework 4/Problem2b.py", line 35, in <module>
    print (longestPalSubsB(s))

  File "/Users/Rayan/Desktop/AUB Spring 2019/EECE 230 /HW/Homework 4/Problem2b.py", line 24, in longestPalSubsB
    if isSubPalindrome (st,i,j) == True and len(st)>MaxLen:

  File "/Users/Rayan/Desktop/AUB Spring 2019/EECE 230 /HW/Homework 4/Problem2b.py", line 12, in isSubPalindrome
    if s[i] != s[end+1-i]:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Please edit the full traceback of the exception into the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And please do not post code in comments; instead, edit your original question.

Comment: @orde sorry that was me, but I thought better of it (luckily)

Comment: When I run the code, `s` is just a single character

Comment: Sorry guys! It is line 4 not line 12 (it was line 12 on python 3 because of all the comments in the beginning) my bad!

Comment: That's fine @RayanAlHobayb. I figured that it was on that line

Comment: @RayanAlHobayb Any time you're asking a question about code that's generating an exception, it's good to get into the habit of including the full traceback. In many cases a lot more information can be gathered from that than just "I got a String index out of range on line 4".

Comment: @glibdud I am sorry but I don't know what is a traceback. I am really new to coding :/ Can you tell me where can I get that from?

Comment: If you run the program in python IDLE, you will be able to see and copy the error message.

Comment: You mean this??

Answer (score 1):

Python `range(start, end)` give you a sequence of numbers from `start` to `end-1` inclusive. For example, `range(10, 14)` is 10, 11, 12, 13. Now consider this loop:

```
for i in range (start,end):
    if s[i] != s[end-i]:
        isPal = False
```

the `if` part, if using my example of `range(10, 14)`, is comparing `s[10] != s[14-10]` up to `s[13] != s[14-13]`. Obviously not what you intended to do.

Possibly you mean this:

```
for i in range(end-start):
    if s[start+i] != s[end-i]:
        isPal = False
```

To solve your problem, there is a (long) one-liner to do it:

```
print(max([s[i:j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i+1, len(s)) if s[i:j+1] == "".join(reversed(s[i:j+1]))], key=lambda x: len(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That might be the problem. But even so after changing it I get the same error. I will try and see what I can do! Thanks

Comment: your algorithm in longestPalSubsB has a lot of off-by-one error

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Think what `range()` and `len()` gives you and fix it. If you use my change, the `st` you passed into the function covers only `start` to `end-1` but you expect `start` to `end`, also you should use `k` instead of `j` as parameter to `isSubPalindrome`

Comment: I added a +1 here (if isSubPalindrome (st,i,j+1) == True) but that didn't help. I also removed all the -1 after len(s)

Comment: I would suggest to rewrite the whole `longestPalSubsB` function

Comment: I will try doing that now

Comment: added a one-liner as a solution for you as a starter

Comment: Thank you. But I am afraid that won't do :( We have restrictions for this code. We can only do what we learnt in class and specifically for this question we should not use slicing (except for the return) because we solved the same question with slicing before

Comment: Okay so I came up with this : def longestPalSubsB (s):
    
    MaxLen = 0
    for i in range (len(s)):
        for j in range (i,len(s)):
            st = ""
            for k in range (i,j):
                st = st + st[k]
                Len = len (st)
                if Len > MaxLen and isSubPalindrome (st,0,Len):
                    MaxLen = Len
                    start = i
                    end = j + 1
    return s[start:end]

Comment: Oops .. sorry about that, how can I show it to you without it turning all sticked together?

Comment: Try use `MaxLen = j-1`, `isSubPalindrome(s, i, j)`, and do not use `st`

Comment: what should I use instead of st? I can't use s because s is the input

Comment: Finally ! Its working !! :DDDDDD Thank you so much for your time and help kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code including logic to check for palindrome.

### Synactical Errors:

In longestPalSubsB function, variable 'i' ranges from 0 to len(s)-1. 
`range(n)` ranges from 0 to `n-1`. Hence `for i in range(len(s)):` syntax should be used. Similar syntax is applicable for `j`.

Suppose `str = "STARWARS"`, `str[0:1]` returns `'S'` and `str[1:4]` returns "TAR".

`return s[start,end]` throws syntax error. It should be `s[start:end+1]`

### Logical Errors:

In `isSubPalindrome` function, variable `i` should be used to compare last and first characters, second last and second characters and so on. Below code should do the trick.

```
def isSubPalindrome (s):
    isPal = True
    n = len(s)
    mid = int(n/2)
    for i in range(mid):
        if s[i] != s[n-1-i]:
            isPal = False
    return isPal
```

You don't need third loop of k in `longestPalSubsB` function. Use `st = s[i:j+1]`, `isSubPalindrome (st)`

You may want to check syntax by using interactive python shell which can spawned by typing `python` in your terminal or cmd. `python -i test.py` gives a interactive python shell which has variable values of your code. Happy Python coding!!

Comment: Thank you sir! :3 I was finally able to fix my algorithm and your remark helped quite a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is the working code :)

```
def isSubPalindrome (s,start,end):
    isPal = True
    st = s[start:end]
    mid = int(len(st)/2)
    n = len(st)
    for i in range (mid):
        if st[i] != st[n-1-i]:
            isPal = False

    return isPal

def longestPalSubsB (s):

    MaxLen = 0
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for i in range (len(s)):
        for j in range (i,len(s)):
            st = []
            Len = 0
            for k in range (i,j+1):
                st.append(s[k])
                Len = len (st)
                if Len > MaxLen and isSubPalindrome (s,i,j+1):
                    MaxLen = Len
                    start = i 
                    end = j + 1
    return s[start:end]


s = input("Enter a string: ")

print (longestPalSubsB(s))
```